# Convert dictionary of tuples to dataframe

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary:

```
{'A': ({'A': 0,
   'B': 0.07142857142857142,
   'J': 0.125,
   'C': 0.2,
   'G': 0.26785714285714285,
   'F': 0.6011904761904762,
   'D': 1.2,
   'E': 1.3111111111111111},
  {'A': ['A'],
   'B': ['A', 'B'],
   'C': ['A', 'C'],
   'J': ['A', 'J'],
   'F': ['A', 'J', 'G', 'F'],
   'G': ['A', 'J', 'G'],
   'D': ['A', 'C', 'D'],
   'E': ['A', 'C', 'D', 'E']}),
 'B': ({'B': 0,
   'A': 0.07142857142857142,
   'J': 0.19642857142857142,
   'C': 0.27142857142857146,
   'G': 0.3392857142857143,
   'F': 0.6726190476190477,
   'D': 1.2714285714285714,
   'E': 1.3825396825396825},
  {'B': ['B'],
   'A': ['B', 'A'],
   'C': ['B', 'A', 'C'],
   'J': ['B', 'A', 'J'],
   'F': ['B', 'A', 'J', 'G', 'F'],
   'G': ['B', 'A', 'J', 'G'],
   'D': ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'],
   'E': ['B', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E']}),
 'C': ({'C': 0,
   'A': 0.2,
   'B': 0.27142857142857146,
   'J': 0.325,
   'G': 0.46785714285714286,
   'F': 0.8011904761904762,
   'D': 1.0,
   'E': 1.1111111111111112},
  {'C': ['C'],
   'A': ['C', 'A'],
   'D': ['C', 'D'],
   'B': ['C', 'A', 'B'],
   'J': ['C', 'A', 'J'],
   'F': ['C', 'A', 'J', 'G', 'F'],
   'G': ['C', 'A', 'J', 'G'],
   'E': ['C', 'D', 'E']}),
 'D': ({'D': 0,
   'E': 0.1111111111111111,
   'F': 1.0,
   'C': 1.0,
   'A': 1.2,
   'B': 1.2714285714285714,
   'J': 1.325,
   'G': 1.3333333333333333},
  {'D': ['D'],
   'E': ['D', 'E'],
   'F': ['D', 'F'],
   'C': ['D', 'C'],
   'G': ['D', 'F', 'G'],
   'A': ['D', 'C', 'A'],
   'B': ['D', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
   'J': ['D', 'C', 'A', 'J']}),
 'E': ({'E': 0,
   'D': 0.1111111111111111,
   'F': 1.1111111111111112,
   'C': 1.1111111111111112,
   'A': 1.3111111111111111,
   'B': 1.3825396825396825,
   'J': 1.4361111111111111,
   'G': 1.4444444444444444},
  {'E': ['E'],
   'D': ['E', 'D'],
   'F': ['E', 'D', 'F'],
   'C': ['E', 'D', 'C'],
   'G': ['E', 'D', 'F', 'G'],
   'A': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'A'],
   'B': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
   'J': ['E', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'J']}),
 'F': ({'F': 0,
   'G': 0.3333333333333333,
   'J': 0.47619047619047616,
   'A': 0.6011904761904762,
   'B': 0.6726190476190476,
   'C': 0.8011904761904762,
   'D': 1.0,
   'E': 1.1111111111111112},
  {'F': ['F'],
   'D': ['F', 'D'],
   'G': ['F', 'G'],
   'A': ['F', 'G', 'J', 'A'],
   'J': ['F', 'G', 'J'],
   'B': ['F', 'G', 'J', 'A', 'B'],
   'C': ['F', 'G', 'J', 'A', 'C'],
   'E': ['F', 'D', 'E']}),
 'G': ({'G': 0,
   'J': 0.14285714285714285,
   'A': 0.26785714285714285,
   'F': 0.3333333333333333,
   'B': 0.3392857142857143,
   'C': 0.46785714285714286,
   'D': 1.3333333333333333,
   'E': 1.4444444444444444},
  {'G': ['G'],
   'J': ['G', 'J'],
   'F': ['G', 'F'],
   'A': ['G', 'J', 'A'],
   'B': ['G', 'J', 'A', 'B'],
   'C': ['G', 'J', 'A', 'C'],
   'D': ['G', 'F', 'D'],
   'E': ['G', 'F', 'D', 'E']}),
 'J': ({'J': 0,
   'A': 0.125,
   'G': 0.14285714285714285,
   'B': 0.19642857142857142,
   'C': 0.325,
   'F': 0.47619047619047616,
   'D': 1.325,
   'E': 1.4361111111111111},
  {'J': ['J'],
   'G': ['J', 'G'],
   'A': ['J', 'A'],
   'B': ['J', 'A', 'B'],
   'C': ['J', 'A', 'C'],
   'F': ['J', 'G', 'F'],
   'D': ['J', 'A', 'C', 'D'],
   'E': ['J', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E']})}
```

And I want to convert it to a dataframe like this one:

```
person     connected_person     distance     path
A                 A                O          ['A']
A                 B                0.07       ['A','B']
A                 C                0.2        ['A','C']
A                 D                1.2        ['A','C','D']
A                 E                1.3        ['A','C','D','E']
A                 F                0.6        ['A','J','G','F']
A                 G                0.26       ['A','J','G']
A                 J                0.125      ['A','J']  
B                 A
B                 B
B                 C
B                 D
B                 E
B                 F
B                 G
B                 J
C                 A
C                 B
C                 C
C                 D
C                 E
C                 F
C                 G
C                 J
D                 A
D                 B
D                 C
D                 D
D                 E
D                 F
D                 G
D                 J
E                 A
E                 B
E                 C
E                 D
E                 E
E                 F
E                 G
E                 J
F                 A
F                 B
F                 C
F                 D
F                 E
F                 F
F                 G
F                 J
G                 A
G                 B
G                 C
G                 D
G                 E
G                 F
G                 G
G                 J
J                 A
J                 B
J                 C
J                 D
J                 E
J                 F
J                 G
J                 J
```

I didn't complete the dataframe for all the persons but the idea is the same: For each person (each key of the dict) I want a column with the person they are connected with, which comes from the first item of each key, the distance between them (which also comes from the first item) and the path taken to reach each node (which comes from the second item of the dict).

Thanks!

Comment: You have provided a problem statement. That's cool and all, but what is your question? Did you _try_ to get what you want? It seems there's no calculation involved, only a restructuring of your data structure before you can create a dataframe like you want

Comment: Of course I tried to get what I want. But I couldn't, that's why I'm asking for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Let `d` be your dictionary. Then you could do this as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['person', 'connected_person', 'distance', 'path']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
for person, (distances, paths) in d.items():
    n = len(distances)
    df_person = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
    connected_people = sorted(distances.keys())
    df_person['connected_person'] = connected_people
    df_person['distance'] = [distances[key] for key in connected_people]
    df_person['path'] = [paths[key] for key in connected_people]
    df_person['person'] = person
    df = pd.concat([df, df_person])

print(df)
```

prints

| index | person | connected_person | distance | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | A | 0.0 | A |
| 1 | A | B | 0.07142857142857142 | A,B |
| 2 | A | C | 0.2 | A,C |
| 3 | A | D | 1.2 | A,C,D |
| 4 | A | E | 1.3111111111111111 | A,C,D,E |
| 5 | A | F | 0.6011904761904762 | A,J,G,F |
| 6 | A | G | 0.26785714285714285 | A,J,G |
| 7 | A | J | 0.125 | A,J |
| 0 | B | A | 0.07142857142857142 | B,A |
| 1 | B | B | 0.0 | B |

Comment: Thanks for this answer! However, I'm getting an error I can't solve on line:
 
df_person['distance'] = [distances[key] for key in keys]

NameError: name 'keys' is not defined

Comment: @TomasC8 should be fixed now